# Transpose subarray data from indexed to associative

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, transpose

**I'm making an API for getting some data. My API gives object data like given, given object I wanted to format some data inside object:**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "productId": 55,
      "productTitle": "Test product",
      "variation": {
        "Color": "Red",
        "Size": "XS",
        "din": "10190537",
        "product_id": 55,
        "name": [
          "Color",
          "Size"
        ],
        "value": [
          "Red",
          "XS"
        ]
      },
      "din": "10190537",
      "markets": [
        {
          "id": 11,
          "name": "paytmmall",
          "displayName": "PayTm Mall",
          "identifierName": "Product_Id"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**In this object I want data like given**

```
 {
  "data": [
    {
      "productId": 55,
      "productTitle": "this is test from hariom",
      "variation": {
        "Color": "Red",
        "Size": "XS",
        "din": "10190537",
        "product_id": 55,
        "variationTypes": [
          {
            "name": "Color",
            "value": "Red"
          },
          {
            "name": "Size",
            "value": "XS"
          }
        ],
        
      },
      "din": "10190537",
      "markets": [
        {
          "id": 11,
          "name": "paytmmall",
          "displayName": "PayTm Mall",
          "identifierName": "Product_Id"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Here Is my Controller Name**

```
public function MarketMapping(Request $request)
    {
        $sellerId =  Auth::guard('seller-api')->user();
        $page = $request->has('pageNumber') ? $request->get('pageNumber') : 1;
        $limit = $request->has('perPage') ? $request->get('perPage') : 10;
        $variationFromInvTbl =  ProductInventory::select('Color', 'Size', 'din', 'product_id')->where('seller_id', $sellerId->id)->where('status', 'active')->limit($limit)->offset(($page - 1) * $limit)->get();
        $dataArray = array();
        foreach($variationFromInvTbl as $key => $varitionValue)
        {
            $prodtsFromLivetbl = ProductsLive::select('productTitle', 'product_id')->where('product_id', $varitionValue->product_id)->get();
            foreach ($prodtsFromLivetbl as $key => $value)
            {
                $marketChannelData = DB::table('market_channels')
                                ->join('sellers_market_channels', 'market_channels.name', '=', 'sellers_market_channels.key')
                                //->join('market_product_mappings', 'market_channels.id', '=', 'market_product_mappings.market_id')
                                ->select('market_channels.id','market_channels.name', 'market_channels.displayName','market_channels.identifierName') //'market_product_mappings.identifierValue'
                                ->where('sellers_market_channels.seller_id', $sellerId->id)
                                ->where('sellers_market_channels.value', 1)
                                ->get();
                $maketProductMap = MarketProductMapping::where('seller_id', $sellerId->id)->where('product_id', $varitionValue->product_id)->where('din', $varitionValue->din)->pluck('identifierValue');
                if (count($maketProductMap))
                {
                    $marketChannelData[$key]->value = $maketProductMap[0];
                }
                $varitionValue['name']= array_keys($varitionValue->only(['Color', 'Size']));
                $varitionValue['value'] = array_values($varitionValue->only(['Color', 'Size']));
                    $dataObject = ((object)[
                    "productId"     => $value->product_id,
                    "productTitle"  => $value->productTitle,
                    "variation"     => $varitionValue,
                    "din"           => $varitionValue['din'],
                    "markets"       => $marketChannelData
                ]);
                array_push($dataArray,$dataObject);
            }
        }
        if($variationFromInvTbl)
        {
            $response['success']        = true;
            $response["page"]           = $page;
            $response["itemPerPage"]    = $limit;
            $response["totalRecords"]   = $this->CountMarketMapping($page, $limit, $sellerId->id);
            $response['data']           = $dataArray;
            return response()->json($response, 200);
        }else{
            $response['success'] =  false;
            $response['data']    =  $prodtsFromLivetbl;
            return response()->json($response, 409);
        }
    }
```

Comment: A complete and clear question needs a [mcve]. We want your sample input, your best coding attempt, your current result, your desired output, and a plain English explanation of the required logic.

Comment: Please improve/complete your question so that it can be reopened and so that Stack Overflow collects hogher quality questions.

Comment: Why did you accept the answer, it clearly does not transpose the subarray data. (And it doesn't include an explanation.)  Please be more careful about when/where you award the green tick.  I will post a correct transposing answer AFTER you [edit] your question to include all requested details.

Comment: so sorry sir i'm respecting all member and also this community It always helped me, sir please help me to find solution

Comment: sure sir, thank for encourage me

Comment: You have added way too much irrelevant noise to your question.  You need only focus on `$varitionValue->only(['Color', 'Size'])` and how to restructure that subarray.  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using laravel's [only()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-only) method which returns an associative array.

You wish to convert each key-value pair into a subarray containing two associative elements -- the original key will be the value of the `name` element
and the original value will be the value of the `value` element.

By passing the original array keys and array values into `array_map()`, you can iterate them both synchronously.

`compact()` is a perfect native function to create the desired associative subarrays from the iterated parameters.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/X2cG4))

```
$variations = $varitionValue->only(['Color', 'Size']);

$dataObject = (object)[
    // ... your other data
    'variations' => array_map(
        function($name, $value) {
            return compact(['name', 'value']);
        },
        array_keys($variations),
        $variations
    ),
    // ...your other data
];

var_export($dataObject);
```

Output:

```
(object) array(
   'variations' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'name' => 'Color',
      'value' => 'Red',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'name' => 'Size',
      'value' => 'XS',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This script will help you

```php
<?php

$data = [
    "variation" => [
        [
            "Color"      => "Red",
            "Size"       => "XS",
            "din"        => "10190537",
            "product_id" => 55,
            "name" => [
                "0" => "Color",
                "1" => "Size"
            ],
            "value" => [
                "0" => "Red",
                "1" => "XS"
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

for ($i=0; $i < count($data["variation"]); $i++) { 
    $data["variation"][$i]["data"]["name"] = $data["variation"][$i]["name"];
    $data["variation"][$i]["data"]["value"] = $data["variation"][$i]["value"];

    unset($data["variation"][$i]["name"]);
    unset($data["variation"][$i]["value"]);
}

print_r($data);
```

**output**

```
Array
(
    [variation] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Color] => Red
                    [Size] => XS
                    [din] => 10190537
                    [product_id] => 55
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Color
                                    [1] => Size
                                )

                            [value] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Red
                                    [1] => XS
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: "Use this script" answers are low value on Stack Overflow because they miss an opportunity to educate and empower the OP and thousands of future researchers.

Comment: When you answer "requirements dump" questions, you are effectively perpetuating the myth that Stack Overflow is a free code writing service where it is "okay" to get other developers to do your job for free.  Please require more of a question before you consider answering.

Comment: This answer is: 1. Provably incorrect 2. Unexplained 3. To a no-effort question.  For these reasons, I must downvote this answer which is no good to Stack Overflow.